# Angular write into nested scope properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have multiple "input field and a button" couples in my app.
The button opens up a dialog to write something into the text field.

```
[ input ] [ button ] ---> [ dialog ( ok ) ( cancel ) ]
```

I've used Bootstrap.UI.Modal ( https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal ) so I have a promise to deal with it:

```
//html
<input ng-model="foo"/>
<button ng-click="dialog('foo')"> Open </button>

//controller
modalInstance.result.then(
    function ( selectedItem ) {
        $scope[ arg ] = selectedItem;
    }, 
    ...
);
```

Everything works okay. ( [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VdWpelYzuG0JdJglRjru?p=preview) )
The problem comes when I have to access nested properties of my scope objects:

```
...
<input ng-model="foo"/>
<button ng-click="dialog('foo')"> Open </button>
...
<li ng-repeat="thing in model.nested.properties.of.unknown.level">
    ...
    <input ng-model="thing.foo"/>
    <button ng-click="dialog( '???' )"> Open </button>
    ...
```

What I want to know is: what is the best approach to achieve that?

Until now I tried:

- passing the scope variable into the returning callback, but it got only the value, not the reference; so the field would not be updated.

  ```
   resolve: {
       field: function() {
         return $scope[ field ];
       }
   }
  ```
- passing an array of strings to recreate the scope hierarchy

  ```
   dialog( ["a","b","c"] ) --> $scope[ "a" ][ "b" ][ "c" ] = output.value;
  ```
- preparing an object of callbacks like

  ```
   object = { 
     "one": function(){ $scope.a.b.c = ... }, 
     "two": function(){ $scope.d.e.f = ... }, 
     ... 
     // but this requires that I know in advance 
     // how many level I will nest into the $scope
   }
  ```
- using the id of the input field, so you can write directly into the DOM (but as far as I know this is not a good approach in angularjs)

  ```
   $("#input-abc...").val( ... )
  ```
- using eval (uungh...)

I think that the first solution would be the best one, but how can I pass the reference of the nested scope element to my promise callback? 
There are some best practices to achieve this?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To treat nested structures, you could simple pass your container alongside field name:

```
resolve: {
    container: function () { 
      return thing; // thing would come from edit() parameter
    },
    field: function () {
      return fieldName;
    }
  }
```

And then access your data from container instead of scope. This would be the poor-man 2-way binding.

--

Another approach, taking where you left at your directive, would be as follows:

step 1) as you're using a `ngModel`, add it to directive scope to get 2-way binding:

```
scope: {
  ngModel: '='
},
```

step 2) add `attr` parameter to link

```
link: function (scope, element, attr)
```

step 3) make field resolve to data passed in view

```
resolve: {
  field: function () {
    return attr.external;
  }
```

step 4) assign new data to ngModel once modal is completed

```
scope.ngModel = output.selection;
```

step 5) change your view like this:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='thing.value' external="{{thing.label}}"/> Value: {{thing.value}}
```

Fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/hj6gOITk0rkHwPqSN9Tf?p=preview

Comment: Could you elaborate in a better way the first solution? what do you mean with "thing would come from edit() parameter"? A working fiddle would be awesome, too!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider all you data with the same structure if possible, so you don't have to work on conditions within your modal.

Even the first and second one:

```
 $scope.first = {label:'first',value:'initial value'};
 $scope.second = {label:'second ', value:'initial value'};
```

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IIj15t3kUHniwYggqwjy?p=preview)

Comment: I would if I could, but it's not possible in my case

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work:

I created a directive to set the value you obtain from the promise directly on the val( ) of the element.

```
.directive("external", function( $modal ){

 return {

    restrict: "A",

    link: function (scope, element) {

      element.bind("mousedown", function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          resolve: {
            field: function() {
              return "";
            }
          }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function( output ) {
          element.val( output.selection );
        }, function() {
          $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This way you can access your element without knowing in advance anything.

Working demo ( [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qcj90fdI8LXsravLGl4T?p=preview) )

Comment: updating element through element.val() doesn't reflect on your model.